# Changing the path of reading AVDs for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, path, android-virtual-device

I changed the default directory of AVDs, from `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.android` to `D:\Android\.android`. Android Studio can see virtual devices but VS Code doesn`t. How to change the reading path of the AVDs for VS Code?

I added the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set the new path.